# How to configure a friendly name for the generated user with CLI using non-interactive client login?

Tags: docker, sitecore-cli

### Sitecore 10.2:

I followed the documentation as described [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/configure-a-non-interactive-client-login.html).

Configuration applied to Identity Server and stored at `C:\identity\config\sitecore.identityserver.devex.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>
      <Clients>
        <CliServerClient>
            <ClientId>SitecoreCLIServer</ClientId>
            <ClientName>SitecoreCLIServer</ClientName>
            <AccessTokenType>0</AccessTokenType>
            <AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
            <IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
            <RequireClientSecret>true</RequireClientSecret>
            <AllowOfflineAccess>false</AllowOfflineAccess>
            <AllowedGrantTypes>
                <AllowedGrantType1>client_credentials</AllowedGrantType1>
            </AllowedGrantTypes>
            <ClientSecrets>
                <!--<ClientSecret1>PlaceholderForSuperSecret</ClientSecret1>-->
            </ClientSecrets>
            <AllowedScopes>
                <AllowedScope1>sitecore.profile.api</AllowedScope1>
            </AllowedScopes>
        </CliServerClient>
      </Clients>
    </IdentityServer>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Configuration applied to Sitecore CM role and stored under `~/App_Config/Include`

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">  
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <identityProviders>
        <identityProvider id="SitecoreIdentityServer">
          <transformations>
            <transformation name="admin-ify client credentials users" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="client_id" value="SitecoreCLIServer" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="name" value="sitecore\cliuser" />
                <claim name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin" value="true" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
          </transformations>
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>
    </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

After logging in I see the following username:

```
dotnet sitecore login --authority https://identityx.dev.sxp.local --cm https://scmsx.dev.sxp.local --allow-write true --client-credentials true --client-id SitecoreCLIServer --client-secret 'HIDDEN_FROM_BOBBY_TABLES'
```

**Note:** I found that the client secret has a limit (probably 101). I decided to use a string 64 characters long.

[image: Unfriendly name]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is surprisingly trivial.

First we need to map the `isAdmin` claim to the `IsAdministrator` user property. More information can be found in the official docs [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html).

The patch configuration should contain an additional section for mapping the fields.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <propertyInitializer>
        <maps>
          <map name="set IsAdministrator" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <data hint="raw:AddData">
              <source name="http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin" value="true" />
              <target name="IsAdministrator" value="true" />
            </data>
          </map>
        </maps>
      </propertyInitializer>
    </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Second we need to map the custom name when creating the user.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <identityProvidersPerSites>
        <mapEntry name="all sites">
          <externalUserBuilder>
            <patch:attribute name="type" value="Company.Feature.Security.Services.CustomExternalUserBuilder, Company.Feature"  />
          </externalUserBuilder>
        </mapEntry>
      </identityProvidersPerSites>
    </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Third we need to implement the class which manages the creation of users. Since we defined the username explicitly in the config we'll need to look for that first.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Identity;
using Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services;
using Sitecore.SecurityModel.Cryptography;

namespace Company.Feature.Security.Services
{
    public class CustomExternalUserBuilder : DefaultExternalUserBuilder
    {
        public CustomExternalUserBuilder(ApplicationUserFactory applicationUserFactory, IHashEncryption hashEncryption) : base(applicationUserFactory, hashEncryption)
        {
            Log.Info($"Creating a new instance of {typeof(CustomExternalUserBuilder)}", this);
        }

        protected override string CreateUniqueUserName(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ExternalLoginInfo externalLoginInfo)
        {
            Log.Info($"Preparing to create a new username", this);
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(userManager, nameof(userManager));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(externalLoginInfo, nameof(externalLoginInfo));
            var identityProvider = this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration.GetIdentityProvider(externalLoginInfo.ExternalIdentity);
            if (identityProvider == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to retrieve an identity provider for the given identity");
            }
            
            var nameClaim = externalLoginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "name");
            if(nameClaim != null)
            {
                return nameClaim.Value;
            }

            return base.CreateUniqueUserName(userManager, externalLoginInfo);
        }
    }
}
```