# GraphQL.ExecutionError: Deserialization can only be performed by Sitecore Administrators - client secret

Tags: sitecore-client

Getting below exception when trying to deserialize content in `sandbox` environment. I was trying to find how to generate client secret for non-interactive client login and I could not find articles. SuperUser has not created to authenticate using clientsecret and deserialize.

```
GraphQL.ExecutionError: Deserialization can only be performed by Sitecore Administrators
```

Comment: This may provide some help. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31643/how-to-configure-a-friendly-name-for-the-generated-user-with-cli-using-non-inter